# how webpack builds vue.js project

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

My question is related to webpack. Let's say I'm using webpack and vue.js project. How does webpack build the project when I run the npm run build. I know that there's a build folder where config files have to be added and there'll be output folder dist which will save my final project.

Question 1) WHat does webpack do? Does it search entry point in config file so that it knows where to start building process from? for vue.js it's src/main.js. AM I right?

QUestion 2) when it finds main.js, what does it do? does it go from main.js to top so that to find all the dependencies ?

QUestion 3) Let's say IT found a .vue file. what does it do? does it seperate js code - put it into some other js file, then seperate css and put it into some other css file? or just take the whole .vue code and puts it into js file(with all its html and so on)?

QUestion 4) Just need that line of code what it looks to show me QUestion 3) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, webpack has an entry point (`entry` section from config). It's not `src/main.js` exactly, it's configurable.
2. It builds a dependency tree starting from an entry point.
3. It will be handled with loaders in the sequence you provided. Usually, it's `vue-loader` which transforms vue files to js, next it goes to `babel-loader` which transpiles your js dialect (Flow/ES6/ES2017/TS) to ES5, next ot `js-loader` which can finally split all the code to dependencies and continue loading.

   CSS separation can be done with webpack plugins like `ExtractTextWebpackPlugin` and then your css dialect (LESS/SASS/PostCSS, etc) will be transformed with loaders, i.e. `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, `style-loader`.
4. When styles extraction plugin is not present, it will distribute css along with js and put it to the head styles.

Comment: JUst a little bit question. Let's say I'm using vue-loader. I have entry point src/main.js. THen let's say webpack finds a file example.Vue and in there, I have js scripts , I have html templates and I have css files. WHat does it do? convert this code (js,css,html) into js file or convert js code into js file, convert css code into css file and convert html code in js file or something else. ??

Comment: @GiorgiLagidze, the best option for you is to read webpack's documentation and dive into modules conception it offers